# Python sudoku checker

Tags: python, sudoku

I'm working on an assignment for my CIS class in python. We have to code a Sudoku checker. In a 9x9 board we obviously have to check each row, col and 3x3 square for duplicates. I'm a little stuck on the idea of how to check the numbers by a 3x3 square. Below is my code for checking each row and col, if someone could help me a little with an outline or an approach just something for checking each 3x3 square that would be amazing!

```
self.columns = [ ]
     for col in range(9):
        col_tiles = [ ]
        self.columns.append(col_tiles)
        for row in range(9):
            col_tiles.append(self.tiles[row][col])
self.squares = [ ]
for col in range(1, 10, 3):
        for row in range(1, 10, 3):
            square_tiles = [ ]
            self.squares.append(square_tiles)
            for x in range(3):
                for y in range(3):
                    square_tiles.append(self.tiles[x][y])
```

Comment: The code snippet you've shown doesn't actually do any checks.  But assuming you have a function `def isListValid(self, valueList)` which checks that the `valueList` has one of every digit, you can use this to check each column, row and square.  To get the values from a 3x3 square, you need to write a loop over three rows, with an inner loop over three columns to get nine items total.

Comment: I've removed the homework tag: The tag is obsolete and it's clear from the question that this is homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you have the freedom to read the data and structure how you want. We want a set of unique values 1-9 for each row/column/3x3 grid, so one way is to either use a `set` or a list comparison (we'll use `set` here to make it cleaner). If we create a set equal to the numbers from 1 to 9, we have a point against which we can compare all of our other groups. Assume a structure like this (from [here](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/data/sudoku32.gif)):

```
In [1]: r1 = [9,3,2,5,4,8,1,7,6]

In [2]: r2 = [1,8,7,9,2,6,5,4,3]

In [3]: r3 = [5,4,6,3,7,1,2,8,9]

# Continues....
```

Where each row represents a full row of data. Now lets create a section of that data that represents the first three rows, pull out one grid and compare the contents to our set:

```
In [4]: sec1 = [r1, r2, r3]

In [5]: nums = set(range(1, 10))

In [6]: nums == set(n for row in sec1 for n in row[:3])
Out[6]: True
```

This iterates over the first three rows and returns the first three elements in each of those rows. To get a better visual, here is the equivalent `for`-loop code to make it a bit easier to decipher:

```
result = set()
for row in sec1:
    for n in row[:3]:
      result.add(n)
```

Since our set of numbers includes everything from 1-9, we know it is valid. To move to the second, we range the `row[:3]` to `row[3:6]` (and `row[6:9]` after that). You'll then need to handle this for the next two sections as well. I'll leave it to you as to how to wrap this in a more dynamic structure (note the multiples of three), but hopefully this will get you started :)

Comment: Is this really the best way to approach this though, I mean it works assuming that the submitted board doesn't have intentional problems that would trip this up. I mean if I have a square with 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 it would sum to 45 and this would return a valid square even though its not a valid square

Comment: is there not a way to do it that is more like my initial code. I mean this would totally work but I need something much simpler and straight forward.

Comment: @user1758231 Sure, we can find something. What are you allowed to use? Is it the `set` concept that doesn't mesh with what you need? If we changed the `for` loop to compare against a list, would that work better? Keeping it simple, one approach would involve iterating over the rows in sets of three (so 1-3 in the first iteration, 4-6, 7-9) and then iterating through columns of three inside of that. Is that closer to what you want?

Comment: Basically what I think I need is for loops that go through rows, cols. Every three rows I'd iterated over 3 cols, etc moving through the board for each square. That's what I'm not understanding how to do, is how to translate that into code, every time I try I get errors.

I can supply more of the code if that'd help

Comment: @user1758231 Are you familiar with the `step` argument to `range`? Instead of going one item at a time, you can use the step argument to say something like 'return every third number from 1 to 9' (which would be `range(1, 10, 3)`). Now, you can get the beginning of each 3-row or 3-column block by using `for row in range(1, 10, 3)` - how would you access the first, second and third rows/columns during each iteration?

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing it that way, that would work. So after getting each 3rd step for rows and cols, how would i then iterate over those values starting from those positions I just got? just do for loops inside that in range of 3?

Comment: @user1758231 Exactly. Think of it this way - you are iterating over every third item. If you are on item 1, isn't item 2 just the first item + 1? And the second item the first item +2? So if you are iterating over the range 1-10, in order to represent something like 8, you will be on the last part of the 'main' loop (where your number will be 7), so you just say 'n+1'. Does that make sense? I have a tendency to ramble :)

Comment: yeah that makes sense! I think I got it mainly figured out, now I just have to get my indexing for adding it to a list correctly! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @user1758231 That's all you man, nice work! Good luck with everything.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're having trouble coming up with an algorithm, just ask yourself: "How would I solve this manually, *if the only way I could be given the problem was by a computer*".

In other words, if I asked you to check the top left 3x3 grid, your eyes would just go to the top left corner and add up numbers. But if I said, check the top left 3x3 grid, and *didn't actually give you the board*, you'd say, "OK, give me the top left 3x3 grid".

And I'd say "How?"

And you'd say, "Imagine the tiles are numbered by rows and columns. I want the tiles in spots (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), and (2,2)"

Does that help?

Comment: that does help, i understand the idea behind it, the problem is actually implementing it. We want to check (0,0) to (2,2) then move to the next square which is (0,3) to (2,5) then (0,6) to (2,8). I'm stuck on how to actually do this. I figure we probably want for loops for rows and cols, but I get stuck there on how to distinguish a square.

Comment: Loop over the rows and within that loop, loop over the columns, going from 0 to 2 for the top-left etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do: create 3 dictionaries, one for the rows, one for the columns, and one for the 3x3 squares.

while you loop through each element in the sudoku puzzle, keep track of your row and column (trivial), and use if statements to keep track of which 3x3 square you're in (a bit more involved)

then just send each element to the corresponding row, column, and 3x3 square dictionary, and compare at the end.

This way you only need to inspect each element once.

EDIT: also, `set` will probably be useful

Answer (score 0):

This function will do. "sample" gives the randomness, so every time you run this you will get a different one.

```
from random import sample
def generate_sudoku_checker():
    random_list = sample([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],9)
    random_list = random_list + random_list[:9]
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(random_list[i+j*3:i+j*3+9])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is my solution to this :

Funtion:

```
def check_sudoku(lis):
    n = len(lis)
    digit = 1  #start from one
    while (digit<=n):
        i=0
        while i<n:  # go through each row and column
            row_count=0
            column_count=0
            j=0
            while j < n: # for each entry in the row / column
                if lis[i][j] == digit: # check row count
                    row_count = row_count+1
                if lis[j][i]== digit :
                   column_count = column_count+1

             j=j+1
           if row_count !=1 or column_count!=1:
             return False
           i=i+1 # next row/column
        digit = digit+1 #next digit
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but this worked for me:

```
def insert_sudoku():
 puzzle = []
 for i in range(9):
     print("You've entered", len(puzzle), "rows so far")
     row = input("Enter a row")
     if len(row) < 9:
         print("Not enough numbers on this row")
         return insert_sudoku()
     elif len(row) > 9:
         print("Too many numbers. Try again!")
         return insert_sudoku()

    try:
        row = [int(dig) for dig in row]
        puzzle.append(row)
    except:
        print("Whoops, looks like you didn't enter only numbers somewhere. Try again!")
        return insert_sudoku()

validate_entries(puzzle)

def validate_entries(puzzle):

 check = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

 b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9 = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

 for i in range(9):
    z = []
    for x in range(9):
        z.append(puzzle[i][x])
    puzzle.append(z)

 for i in range(3):
    b1 += (puzzle[i][:3])
    b4 += (puzzle[i][3:6])
    b7 += (puzzle[i][6:])

 for i in range(3,6):
    b2 += (puzzle[i][:3])
    b5 += (puzzle[i][3:6])
    b8 += (puzzle[i][6:])

 for i in range(6,9):
    b3 += (puzzle[i][:3])
    b6 += (puzzle[i][3:6])
    b9 += (puzzle[i][6:])

 puzzle.append(b1)
 puzzle.append(b2)
 puzzle.append(b3)
 puzzle.append(b4)
 puzzle.append(b5)
 puzzle.append(b6)
 puzzle.append(b7)
 puzzle.append(b8)
 puzzle.append(b9)

 for iter in puzzle:
     if sorted(iter) != check:
         print("No")
         return

     print("Yes")

 insert_sudoku()
```

Inspired by [this article](https://getanadmin.com/python-3-8/sudoku-validator-using-python/)

EDIT: Indentation might be off from copy + pasting the code.

Answer (score 0):

What my answer adds is the use of a list comprehension to extract the tiles from the board.

```
    """
    # good
    board=[
    [2,9,5,7,4,3,8,6,1],
    [4,3,1,8,6,5,9,2,7],
    [8,7,6,1,9,2,5,4,3],
    [3,8,7,4,5,9,2,1,6],
    [6,1,2,3,8,7,4,9,5],
    [5,4,9,2,1,6,7,3,8],
    [7,6,3,5,2,4,1,8,9],
    [9,2,8,6,7,1,3,5,4],
    [1,5,4,9,3,8,6,7,2]
    ]
    """
    # bad
    board = [
    [1,9,5,7,4,3,8,6,2],
    [4,3,1,8,6,5,9,2,7],
    [8,7,6,1,9,2,5,4,3],
    [3,8,7,4,5,9,2,1,6],
    [6,1,2,3,8,7,4,9,5],
    [5,4,9,2,1,6,7,3,8],
    [7,6,3,5,2,4,1,8,9],
    [9,2,8,6,7,1,3,5,4],
    [2,5,4,9,3,8,6,7,1]
    ]
    
    def check(l):
        # each digit 1-9 should occur once 
        for n in range(1,10):
            try:
                l.index(n)
            except ValueError:
                return False
        return True
        
# check the rows
for row in board:
    print(check(row))
    
# check the columns
for column in [ [ board[r][c] for r in range(9) ] for c in range(9) ]:
    print(check(column))
    
# check the tiles
for tile in [[board[r][c] for r in range(row, row + 3) for c in range(col, col + 3)] for row in range(0, 9, 3) for col in range(0, 9, 3)]:
    print(check(tile))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I also want to confirm the time and space complexity of this code:

```py
"""
Sample input 1:
295743861
431865927
876192543
387459216
612387495
549216738
763524189
928671354
154938672

Output: YES!

Sample input 2
195743862
431865927
876192543
387459216
612387495
549216738
763524189
928671354
254938671

Output: NOPE!!
"""
##################Solution############################################
def get_input():
    #Get the input in form of strings and convert into list
    print("Enter the board here: ")
    lines = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
        final = [(list(i)) for i in lines]
    return final


def row_check(board):
    # row check function which will be used in other two functions as well
    text = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    x = True
    for row in board:
        if sorted(row) == text:
            x = True
        else:
            x = False
    return x


def col_check(board):
    # Getting the list of 9 lists containing column elements
    i = 0
    j = 0
    cols = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
    for j in range(0, 9):
        for i in range(0, 9):
            cols[j].append(board[i][j])
    return (row_check(cols))


def tile_check(board):
    #Getting the list of 9 lists converting each tile of 3x3 into 9 element list
    lst =[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    while k<9:
        for r in range(i,i+3):
            for c in range(j, j+3):
                lst[k].append(board[r][c])
        j = j +3
        k = k +1
        if j == 9:
            j = 0
            i = i+3       
    return (row_check(lst))
        
#main program
c = get_input()
if row_check(c) and col_check(c) and tile_check(c):
    print("YES!")
else:
    print("NOPE!!")
```